# How to collapse comments in NetBeans template?

Tags: java, templates, netbeans

I'm somewhat of a novice programmer, and would like to include some tips in my NetBeans code by building a custom template. However, my tips are... a bit on the long side. I decided to solve that problem by adding a tag above them in one line comments, something like `//@Djikstra's`. I want those comments to be **automatically folded** so that I don't have to scroll through hundreds of lines of code to get to the real code. *How should this be done?* Pictures below should help illustrate this problem.

[image: What the thing looks like in template]

This is what one tip looks like in template.

[image: What it should look like after auto-generation]

And this is what a tip should look like after auto-generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It you add an editor fold around a comment, you can make it collapsed by default.  For example:

```
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Handy tip">
/* start of comment
  This information is useful...
*/
// </editor-fold>
```

The key here is setting the `defaultstate` to `collapsed` which causes the comment to be collapsed when the file is first opened.